# Pixelated gif in QT

Tags: qt

I'm trying to show a gif file in QT app, using the approach provided in the link:  https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/examples/widgets/widgets/movie?h=5.15

Approach makes use of QMovie object set in a QLabel.

The example works well and fine.

But if I enable High DPI scaling for the app, the gif becomes all pixelated. Please see the screenshots below.

This is the line that I add to enable High DPI scaling.

```
QApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
```

[image]
[image]

Any ideas to get this fixed ?

I have tried the following fixes already:

- `setScaledSize` for the QMovie object
- `setScaledContents(true)` for the QLabel

QT version I'm using is 5.15.2 and platform is Windows.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling`, or rather, what's the problem you want to solve with it? You probably need to accept that anytime you re-scale a low-resolution bitmap, you will introduce pixelation.

Comment: I need the App to scale with the screen resolution/scale. I'm able to do that for images with QPixMap `scaled` method using a 2x image. But the same approach doesn't work for a gif even if I use a 2x gif file.

Comment: So, your question boils down to "why do GIFs scale that much worse than QPixmaps?"?  The answer would be that the former is so much worse than the latter, starting with the limited 256-colour-palette.

Comment: In a  way yes, but both are different classes: `QPixmap` and `QMovie` to be compared.

Comment: How would you suggest to reduce the pixelation for a GIF when scaled ?

Comment: Simple: Don't use GIFs. They're a remnant of the 1990s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems at this moment there is no way to render sharp gifs when scaled using QMovie and QLabel. I have filed a bug for the same in [QT bug tracker](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-93090).

Meanwhile I have found a workaround that works fine. It is done making use of QML in the QWidget system, using [QQuickWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qquickwidget.html).

Let me add the full steps here, so that it is helpful to anyone else who run into this problem:

First we need to add support for Qml and QuickWidgets. I use CMake and Visual Studio. Hence I add the below lines in the CMakeLists.txt file. Equivalent changes needs to be made in the .pro file, if QT Creator is used instead.

```
# I'm only adding the relevant lines for brevity
find_package(Qt5 COMPONENTS Qml QuickWidgets)

target_link_libraries(${APP_TARGET_NAME}
    Qt5::Qml
    Qt5::QuickWidgets)

# Note the --qmldir switch
add_custom_command (TARGET ${APP_TARGET_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${QTDIR}/bin/windeployqt
        --qmldir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/qml
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/$<CONFIG>/${APP_TARGET_NAME}.exe)
```

Then create a `spinner.qml` file inside a folder named `qml`:

```
import QtQuick 2.15

Rectangle {
    width: 12
    height: 12
    AnimatedImage {
        y: 5
        width: 12
        height: 12
        id: spinner
        source: "img/spinner.gif"
        speed: 1.0
    }
}
```

And then load the qml file using QQuickWidget and add the QQuickWidget instance to the QWidget layout.

```
QHBoxLayout *main_layout = new QHBoxLayout();
auto *spinner_gif = new QQuickWidget(QUrl::fromLocalFile(":/spinner.qml"));
main_layout->addWidget(spinner_gif);
this->setLayout(main_layout);
```

The gif that shows up won't be pixelated even when scaled and we can see the GPU in use, in the Task Manager, as expected for a QQuickWidget.

Answer (score 1):

A GIF picture cannot have more than 256 unique colours. When you load such an image into Qt, it is internally represented in that exact format with the palette (of 256 colours) from the GIF representation, even if your hardware might be able to display many more colours.

This also means that when you scale such an image, Qt is not allowed to extend the colour space to render in-between colours - This means that scaled GIF pictures generally *have to* look much worse than scaled high-colour images.

The solution to this is either to transform the QImage you created from a GIF picture into a format with a larger colour space before scaling it (with QImage::convertToFormat) or, better still, don't use GIF images at all. After all, GIF is a format developed 30 years ago and has never really been updated to adapt to modern hardware, and using it, you artificially limit your programs to the capabilities of that format.